# Выборка максимального значения из дублирующихся удаленных строк

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Структура таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается выбрать записи с максимальной датой удаления, которые сгруппированы по одному коду, с условием, что они все удалены. Если записи имеют одинаковый код, но имеют разные статусы удаления, тогда эти записи выбирать не нужно.
В данном примере нужно выбрать записи с id =3, id=4.
Я смог придумать только вот такой запрос в базу данных:

```
SELECT *
FROM analyzes_test
WHERE
  code IN (SELECT code FROM analyzes_test GROUP BY code HAVING count(code)>1)
  AND deleted = (max deleted_date)
```

Но я не знаю как вконец подставить наибольшую дату удаления.

Comment: ну так сгруппировать по code и выбрать `MAX(deleted_date)`

Comment: Сделал так как Вы подсказали. Ошибка - #1111 - Неправильное использование групповых функций
http://joxi.ru/l2Z5w8zcwVdxPm

Comment: я совсем не так подсказал :-)

Comment: Но мне нужно выбрать адишники записей, а не максимальные даты. Может я немного не правильно написал в описании.

Comment: `(code, deleted) IN (SELECT code, max(deleted) FROM analyzes_test GROUP BY code HAVING count(code)>1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте этот запрос:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM analyzes_test t
JOIN (SELECT code, max (deleted_date) deleted_date
FROM analyzes_test 
WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM analyzes_test WHERE deleted_date IS null) AND code IS NOT null
GROUP BY code
HAVING count (code)>1 ) x 
ON t.code=x.code AND t.deleted_date=x.deleted_date
```

[DbFiddle тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b6b59d751b180d40cb2cd4c67950f00)